# How to make a copy of list that is a class attribute in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, copy

I have code that contains a class with an list attribute. I am trying to make a copy of the list that I can edit, without modifying the orignal.

```
class Checkers():
   def __init__(self):
       # -1 red,  0 empty,  1 black
       self.BOARD = [
           [ 0, -1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0, -1], 
           [-1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0], 
           [ 0, -1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0, -1], 
           [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0], 
           [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0], 
           [ 1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0], 
           [ 0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1], 
           [ 1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0], 
       ]

   def select(self):
      temp = list(self.BOARD)
      temp[0][0] = 'x'
      temp = list(self.BOARD)
      print(self.BOARD)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   test = Checkers()
   test.select()
```

When the print statement is called, it prints a list with the first element of 'x' instead of the original BOARD list. What can I do to create a copy that does not point to the original list? I have tried importing the copy library and using copy.copy() and slicing: self.BOARD[:]

Comment: Use `copy.deepcopy()` since it's a 2-d list.

Comment: There's nothing special about class attributes, you copy lists the same way no matter where they're stored.